# Translucent UITableView on a UIPopoverView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am unable to make my `UITableView` on a `UIPopoverView` translucent, Apple style. Here's the code I am using with comments on what I have already tried and found not working. Any help much appreciated!

Please note that I cannot use Storyboard segues as I am launching this popover from a dynamic tableview cell cell prototype.

```
popoverViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TargetPickVC"];
popoverViewController.target = _target;
//popoverViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // Does nothing
//popoverViewController.tableView.alpha = 0.1;  // Does make tableview text lighter

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverViewController];
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = nav.popoverPresentationController;

//popPC.containerView.alpha = 0.1; // Does nothing

nav.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = ((UITableView*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]).frame;
nav.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
popPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
popPC.delegate = self;

//popoverViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // No
//popoverViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // visible
//nav.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // results

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Current result looks like this:
[Opague popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb2Ib.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you actually can use segues with dynamic prototypes - just click on your prototype when pushing **ctrl** and then drag to your target scene. You can preconfigure that VC in -prepareForSegue: method

If you are doing this on iPad then add this line `nav.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`
It should help to remove white background from your popover. But it won't help on iPhone - you will see a black background, which is main window's background. To fix it you will need to change **UIModalPresentationPopover** to **UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext** specifically for iPhone.

But if it won't help and you will continue getting a white background - try to set background color to all layers of your view hierarchy - your navigation controller, TargetPickVC and tour table view. Like this

```
popoverViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
popoverViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
nav.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Hopefully it will help

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately those lines did not produce any visible results. I have updated the code on my question to reflect this.

Comment: The result it not quite what I was after since the popover remains opague, but I guess UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext is more appropriate for iPhone UI, so I marked this correct anyway. Thanks for taking the time on this!